# how do i interact with a pc camera using c++

Tags: c++

i intend to interact with a pc camera using c plus plus. Are there any libraries you can recommend or ways to go about ? The idea is to take shots with a Samsung wireless cam then get the images transferred unto a pc with cam and on the pc show images as per the face detection using the cam . any ideas where to start ?

Comment: Knowing C++, you'll probably end up nuking your house before you get any valid results....

Comment: Consider using `OpenCV` library.

Comment: @Christian: Why? Are you implying that it cannot done in C++?

Comment: @Nawaz - No. It lets you do that and *more* (most often unintentionally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Linux I think [libwebcam](http://www.quickcamteam.net/software/libwebcam) would be a good start. Take a look at the [example viewer](http://www.quickcamteam.net/software/linux/v4l2-software/luvcview/) app to get further details in using it. That is for camera access and general functionality. For face detection I guess you could use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection)(I haven't use it myself for this particular purpose so I cannot comment on its face detection capabilities).